# find index of dataframe in list of tuples and add column with its corresponding index in the list of tuples to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So im trying to make something in python that finds an index of a dataframe within this list of tuples and if the acronym (which corresponds to the index in the dataframe is within the list of tuples with theindex 0, in a new column named cluster within the dataframe add a 0 to the row with that acronym as an index. I'm attaching columns of the list of tuples and the dataframe. Please let me know! Thank you!

| tuple index. | Values. |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | MA, PA, CA |
| 1 | NY, FL |

| DF Index. | Cluster |
| --- | --- |
| NY | 1 |
| MA | 0 |

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Here dataframes are created and indexes are set, from columns 'tuple index.' and 'DF Index.'. The 'Cluster' column is populated with np.nan. A list generator is created that checks rows from the 'df['Values.']' column for a match against the 'DF Index. '. The resulting label is used to get the index from df.index and that number is extracted.
The 'df1['Cluster'] ' column is then populated with these values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'tuple index.': (0, 1), 'Values.': [('MA,PA,CA'), ('NY,FL')]})
df = df.set_index('tuple index.')
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'DF Index.': ('NY', 'MA'), 'Cluster': [np.nan, np.nan]})
df1 = df1.set_index('DF Index.')

q = [df.index[(df['Values.'].str.find(df1.index[i]) != -1)][0] for i in range(0, len(df['Values.']))]
df1['Cluster'] = q

print(df1)
```

Output

```
           Cluster
DF Index.         
NY               1
MA               0
```

To make it more clear, I will analyze the search algorithm into parts.

```
a = df['Values.'].str.find(df1.index[0])#Get indexes where there is a match, where there is none -1
b = (a != -1)#Getting a list with True and False
c = df.index[b]#Apply masking to get the value
d = c[0]#Extracting a number
```